# Check Duplicates & Validation Before inserting bulk data Ms Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to check the duplicate value before inserting the values into table,I'm using split function to insert data in bulk, as like this below

```
   Dim VarItm As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSql As String

VarItm = Split(Me.txtTest, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(VarItm)
    strSql = "insert into tblSplit(Nums,dteDate) values(""" & VarItm(i) & """,#" & Me.txtDateIns & "# )"
    'Debug.Print strSql
    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
Next i
```

but the issue is how we can set validation for such ,this will be long string
More then 60 or 100 comma separated values  as P_000001,P_000002,P_000003 & so on till P_000060
`Like "P_######"`

Also to check for duplicated or existed value in table before inserting ?

Comment: You could let Access throw out the duplicates - set an index on the field that you don't want duplicates in (Indexed - _Yes (No Duplicates)_).

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook
I know that ,but we need some sort of  duplicate value  to be inerted for calculation & what about validation ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the (raw) values into a *temp* table.

Then you can run all sorts of validation and queries to read, filter, and verify data in the temp table before appended the sanitised data/records to tblSplit.

Comment: Depending on the integrity of the raw data, sometimes we'll import everything into text fields to help ensure nothing gets lost in the transfer, then parse the values to their final target types as part of the scrub process.